# Fire JavaScript function from html button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form where on button click, JavaScript function needs to start and a new row in a table needs to be inserted. How can I assemble the JavaScript code properly?

Here is the code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">       
    function addRow()
    {
var table = document.getElementById('table');

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

button.onclick = function() {
    var clone = table.rows[table.rows.length - 2].cloneNode(true);
    clone.cells[0].firstChild.data =
        clone.cells[0].firstChild.data.replace(/(\d+):/,function(str,g1) {
                                                           return (+g1 + 1) + ':';
                                                        });
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(clone);
};
 }
    </SCRIPT>
```

and the html part:

```
<input type=button value='Change' onclick="addRow" />
<br /><br />
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 id="table">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Number 1:</td><td><input value=20 style="width:30px" type=text  maxlength=2/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Number 2:</td><td><input value=25 style="width:30px" type=text  maxlength=2/></td></tr>
<tr><td style="border-top:solid 1px black;border-bottom:solid 1px black;">Sum:</td><td style="border-top:solid 1px black;border-bottom:solid 1px black;"><div>45</div></td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr><td style="border-top:solid 1px black;border-bottom:solid 1px black;">Sum:</td><td style="border-top:solid 1px black;border-bottom:solid 1px black;"><div>45</div></td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: "button" is a reserved word in JavaScript. Rename it to another variable. See: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type=button value='Change' onclick="addRow" />
```

`addRow` is a function. When you're calling a function like this, you need to add the `()`. Also, you should wrap `button` in quotes as it is an attribute value.

Change it to

```
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="addRow()" />
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SXbTt/1)

Comment: @Zee — Yes it is. Not best practice, but certainly valid.

Comment: You're right. XHTML 1.0 strict doesn't like onClick, but HTML5 accepts it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses an event based architecture.

I would recommend investigating jQuery's [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function. If you are dealing with elements which are dynamically added/removed from the page, I would recommend the "on" function instead.

Comment: That´s good but the `live()` function is obsolete and replaced by `on()`.